# Linux list only selected groups a user is part of?

Tags: linux, grep, group

When I use the command groups userid  it list out over 100 groups currently assigned to the user.
I need to list only the groups that contain `abc`.

When I do `groups userid | grep abc`
In the output all the groups are listed (over 100) with groups matching `abc` highlighted.
Is it possible to list only the groups that contain `abc`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
groups <username> | tr ' ' '\n' | grep "abc"
```

The point is that `groups <username>` separates each group with a space while `grep` operates on *lines*. This is why you can simply swap spaces with newline character `\n` using `tr` and then use `grep`.

You can try to use this command without the `| grep "abc"` at the end to see the intermediate result as well.

Comment: It worked However It excluded groups that start with abc. For Example:  abcdef abcxyz. It captured abc_* or if abc appears in between for example ffabcyy

Comment: This is weird. It works for me and it does not exclude the lines starting with "abc"... What happens if you use `grep -e "abc"` instead of `grep "abc"`?

Comment: It has the same result.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's match only the given group names, avoiding any substring matches in other group names:

```
$ groups
foo foobar baz ban bat
$ groups | grep --regexp=foo --regexp=ban --word-regexp
[outputs "foo foobar baz ban bat" with only "foo" and "ban" highlighted]
```

To list only the actual matches:

```
$ groups | grep --only-matching --regexp=foo --regexp=ban --word-regexp
foo
ban
```